# How to dynamically set default ng-options value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

Situation: I need to set the default ng-options value to current year. I was able to set it using ng-init and assigning current year data from data array to the model (see the code below).
Here is html:

```
<select
  ng-model="year_filter"
  ng-init="year_filter = year_data[3]"
  ng-change="filter_years(year_filter); closeProject(); showEditVacay = false"
  ng-options="year.name for year in year_data track by year.value"
  >
</select>
```

In controller,

```
$scope.year_data= [
    {value: '2014', name: '2014'},
    {value: '2015', name: '2015'},
    {value: '2016', name: '2016'},
    {value: '2017', name: '2017'},
    {value: '2018', name: '2018'},
    {value: '2019', name: '2019'}
]
```

However, I need to set the default value dynamically so that I don't have to come back next year and change the index. 
I tried to replace year_data[3] with new Date().getFullYear() but had no luck. Also, in the controller, I tried to generate year data dynamically but wasn't sure how to do it while keeping the first entry of the year data to 2014. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show the controller? You should be able to add (right after your `$scope.year_data...` code) something such as `$scope.year_filter = $scope.year_data[3]`....

Comment: @cale_b that I tried already but didn't work.

Comment: @cale_b  To be more specific, I tried it already and it worked well to set the default value. However, it didn't resolve the issue where I need to set it dynamically based on the current year. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ng-model` points to an object, its object reference has to equal one of the objects in the array of options. So you'd have to loop through `year_data` and set `year_filter` to the correct object:

```
var year = new Date().getFullYear().toString();

for (var i = 0; i < $scope.year_data.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.year_data[i].value === year) {
        $scope.year_filter = $scope.year_data[i];

        break;
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid a loop to find the correct object reference, you can have `year_filter` be the string year:

```
$scope.year_filter = new Date().getFullYear().toString();
```

And change `ng-options`:

```
ng-options="year.value as year.name for year in year_data"
```

Comment: getFullYear returns number. If value of year_data is made as number, then we can directly set year_filter to new Date().getFullYear()

Comment: Good point. Instead, I edited my answer to call `new Date().getFullYear().toString();` to match the `value` property in the options (which is a `string`).

Comment: @FrankModica Ah how could I have not come up with this! Thanks it works.